# How to disable Artifactory checksum comparison

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am generating zip files and their md5 checksum in a Jenkins build job. I am then trying to upload these files to Artifactory with the plugin for Jenkins. When trying to do this Artifactory refuses the files with the message `Status code: 409 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: Checksum error`. it then displays some checksums, none of which are the actual checksums of the files nor the ones in the md5 files.

I am not interested in figuring out the root cause of this issue, I just want to disable whatever functionality is preventing the upload to the Artifactory repository. The md5 files and zip files are congruent when I test them on my local machine so it is something that Artifactory is trying to be smart about.

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading yourfile.zip.md5 before uploading yourfile.zip? If so try uploading yourfile.zip before uploading any *.md5 extentions.